# Is it possible to create a 2nd "Favorites" group in the windows navigation pane?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Right now Windows (7,8) allows you to show a "Favorites" group, where you can add links to various folders, regardless of where they actually reside.

Is it possible to create a 2nd group?  My Favorites is getting filled up, and I'd like to be able to organize them for faster access.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it isn't possible. You can add multiple locations to your favorites but you can't create a favorite's 2.

You could possibly create two share drives separating your two folders that you're looking for, but you're just adding another click.